# Declaring C++ map iterator: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector, iterator

I have the following code:

```
using namespace std;

map<int, vector<string> > map;
map<int, vector<string> >::iterator it;
```

and I get this error on the second line of code:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘int’.
```

Comment: You probably need std:: before your declarations and/or you forgot to include the map include file.

Comment: But I'm using namespace std, so is that necessary? @AnonMail

Comment: No.  But you have not shown that in your code snippet!

Comment: @AnonMail sorry! updated.

Comment: Did you `#include <map>`?

Comment: @jxh yup! the problem is with the second line so I'd guess it's just the iterator that's messing up.

Comment: The second `map` is using your variable named `map`.

Comment: jxh is correct - A hint would be that the syntax highlighter has colored your `map` variable light blue ;)

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/669576)

Comment: @jxh thanks, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is certainly that your variable is the same name as its type (map).
In the second line, the type specifier (<>) is applied onto 'map' the variable, and not onto the type 'map', which makes no sense.

Renaming it should solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to reword this as an answer as opposed to a question, as it is almost surely the correct answer.

Comment: this should be a comment, or try to reframe it.

Comment: (Sorry, didn't know how to comment the first post on the mobile application)

Comment: its ok.. just edit the answer, with some explanation.